# How to set version number in InstallAnywhere from a text file?

Tags: windows, installation, installanywhere

I've created an installer Exe file with InstallAnywhere. This Exe installs some files. This Exe also shows info about current version number. Later I want to change some of the installed files via patches. current version number gets changed after applying patches. How can I show this new version number without re-creating new Exe? Is it possible to read version number from a text file in InstallAnywhere?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using InstallAnywhere 2011 then yes. Refer IA2011UserGuide.pdf under the section 'Setting Project Version at Build Time' for more details.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like the "version" you are asking about is an attribute of your program, not the launcher that you build with IA.

If that's correct, you could make your program read the version string from registry or a text file at startup, and make every patch update that reg string or file artifact as part of its deployable.

One way to get this for free is to have your production environment stamp the jar files' manifest entries with the current source-control build/commit number. That way you always have a way to compare two builds' artifacts versions even if you forgot to bump them manually in the user-presentable-version-string. :)